# Unable to get flask_mysqldb to work with python 3.x

Tags: python, mysql-python, flask-mysql

I have a `flask` application that uses `flask_mysqldb` to connect with database. I had imported `MySQLdb` and `flask_mysqldb` packages to use. Some update today morning screwed this. I had to replace `MySQLdb` with `pymysql` because it is not compatible with Python 3.x as per some threads here. The code is still not working because `flask_mysqldb` uses `MySQLdb` internally. I get the following error:

```
 from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Any help on how I can resolve this is most welcome. I have been googling and going through different threads here and not getting anywhere.

Comment: Did you try installing it?

Comment: ok. i think the issue might be with mysqlclient. that wont install. i get this error: 
src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c:29:10: fatal error: 'mysql.h' file not found
      #include "mysql.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1

Comment: This issue is a very common [question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysqlclient+mysql.h) - you should be able to find a duplicate.